# find many matches in nucleotide sequence with a regex

Tags: regex, perl, while-loop, bioinformatics

I have some gene sequence (see below), and I want to find all open reading frame (start with ATG and stop TAG).

I have tried this:

```
my $file = ('ACCCTGCCCAAAATCCCCCCGATCGATAGAGCTAAATGGCCCATGATGCATCGACTAGCTAGCTAAAATGTCGATCGATACAGCTAATAG');

while($file =~ /(ATG\w+?TAG)/g){
    print $1;           
}
```

but it only gives

```
ATGGCCCATGATGCATCGACTAGATGTCGATCGATACAGCTAATAG
```

how can i get every one?

Comment: Isn't it better to use a module for this sort of thing?

Comment: I would look into biopython, bioperl,biojava,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to find all occurences is to use a zero-width assertion, this will prevent "the eating" of our characters: `(?=ATG\w+?TAG)`.

The problem with this is that we'll get empty matches, so the solution is to use a group:

`(?=(ATG\w+?TAG))`. You will find all occurences in group 1.

**Group 1 output:**

```
ATGGCCCATGATGCATCGACTAG
ATGATGCATCGACTAG
ATGCATCGACTAG
ATGTCGATCGATACAGCTAATAG
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/zG6zJ6)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Result is ok, simply separate them in output:

```
print "$1\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting two matches. To see them, I suggest you print some separator between them:

```
print "$1\n";
```

Then we get the output:

```
ATGGCCCATGATGCATCGACTAG
ATGTCGATCGATACAGCTAATAG
```

If you want to find frames that also occur inside another, then you must make sure to not consume too many characters. Work around that via a looahead:

```
/ATG(?=([ACTG]*+TAG))/g;
```

Then `print "ATG$1\n"`, Output:

```
ATGGCCCATGATGCATCGACTAG
ATGATGCATCGACTAG
ATGCATCGACTAG
ATGTCGATCGATACAGCTAATAG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the start and stop codons in the same frame don't forget to filter the results to the only ones with a length multiple of 3:

```
print "ATG$1\n" if (length($1)%3) == 0 ;
```

If you want to check the six frames available in one sequence, don't forget to check also the complementary chain:

```
$comp_chain = reverse($chain) ;
$comp_chain =~ tr/ATCG/TAGC/ ;
```

You will then obtain the open reading frames from the six reading frames available in a single sequence.